# Bridging sync and async functions: EnterError

Tags: rust, async-await

I need help bridging sync and async Rust code. An async library function only allows to run a sync callback, but I need to execute async code in it.

Specifically, I use the async-capable [tokio-openssl](https://docs.rs/tokio-openssl/) crate to accept TLS connections. But OpenSSL (needed to configure the [SslContext](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/ssl/struct.SslContext.html)) only allows to [register sync callbacks](https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/ssl/struct.SslContextBuilder.html#method.set_client_hello_callback) when certain events happen, e.g. when a ClientHello is received.

I tried to construct a workaround using `futures::executor::block_on(async { ... })` and `tokio::task::spawn_blocking()`, but this results in:

> thread panicked at 'cannot execute `LocalPool` executor from within another executor: EnterError

I made a minimal example to show my problem and my solution approach:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

// Signature cannot be modified, controlled by library
fn user_fn() {
    // Blocks for 10ms
    futures::executor::block_on(async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10)).await;
    });
}

// Function cannot be modified, controlled by library
async fn library(callback: impl Fn()) {
    // Blocks for 10ms
    callback();
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Calling library(user_fn).await would block the runtime for 10ms, causing the async runtime to block.
    // So I thought I could spawn the blocking task on a thread where blocking
    // is acceptable...
    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(|| futures::executor::block_on(library(user_fn))).await?;
    
    // But this crashes with:
    // thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'cannot execute `LocalPool` executor from within another executor: EnterError
    
    println!("Finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a5580f7fa6b3942a2c391905b148707)

I also made a more detailed example showcasing the interface of the library: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=508fb4198266da080b82670a8b1ed83d)

Comment: why an async fonction would block ? that the role of async callback you call to not block. here you spawn blocking to block on something async but that this async function that should take care of not blocking not the main.

Comment: The async function blocks because it calls the sync callback and waits for it to finish, while the sync function is free to do blocking syscalls. Here, because the sync user_fn function blocks on the execution of the async block sleeping for 10ms. So it doesn't block before the callback is executed (which is the idea of a callback), but when it is executed, it blocks the runtime.

Comment: Do you need the result of the async stuff in the callback, or you can "fire-and-forget"?

Comment: Yes, I need the result of the async block, because the callback is supposed to return it

Comment: @linuskmr my point is `library()` should do the spawn blocking not your `main()`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b76db723ac8190706e5785c5374c83f5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the error by using a tokio runtime in one place and a futures runtime in the second, but while this will avoid the `EnterError` because tokio cannot detect a futures runtime is running, it will not fix the real issue - running a runtime inside a runtime, which IIRC can lead to a deadlock.

The real fix is to use [`block_in_place()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.block_in_place.html) in the callback, then run the async code inside. Note this will panic in a current-thread runtime:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

// Signature cannot be modified, controlled by library
fn user_fn() -> u32 {
    // Blocks for 10ms
    tokio::task::block_in_place(|| {
        tokio::runtime::Handle::current().block_on(async move {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10)).await;
            123
        })
    })
}

// Function cannot be modified, controlled by library
async fn library(callback: impl Fn() -> u32) {
    // Blocks for 10ms
    dbg!(callback());
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    library(user_fn).await;

    println!("Finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```rust
fn user_fn() {
    futures::executor::block_on(async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10)).await;
    });
}
```

is not legal you can't use an executor inside another executor:

```
thread panicked at 'cannot execute LocalPool executor from within another executor: EnterError
```

replace with:

```rust
fn user_fn() {
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(5, 0));
}
```

and this run fine. But you should not use `spawn_blocking` to wait on a `async`, it make little sense. Better to do it inside your other function.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

fn user_fn() {
    std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(5, 0));
}

async fn library(
    callback: impl Fn() + std::marker::Send + 'static,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || callback()).await?;

    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    library(user_fn).await?;

    println!("Finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

If you say "can't it's the library" well so the library is wrong to ask for a sync callback.

Comment: The problem is that I can't change the library function, because it is provided by OpenSSL, which is a C library. Forking it also isn't really an option, because integrating an async Rust callback into C seems very hard for me. Also, I can't replace the async code in the user_fn() with equivalent sync code.

Comment: @linuskmr if the callback is call by a C library that even less an option to use async in it. You are doing it wrong. Ask openssl maintainer help cause I can't do more than that.